# Execute Script using Powershell Install-Package

Tags: powershell

currently I am trying to install software using Windows Package Management from a local repository. Right now I am using the nuget provider to get the package. My problem is, that I want to execute a script after the `Install-Package` command.
I found several answers that are directing to a `install.ps1`or `init.ps1`file in a tools folder of the nuget package, but I thing this is related to Visual Studio nuget packages.

How do I start a PowerShell script automatically after the Install-Package command running via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct! You would need to use init.ps1 or install.ps1 if you're using NuGet as a Provider. Unfortunately install.sp1 is no longer supported in Visual Studio 2017.

If the package in question, is not available in NuGet then you might want to use a different provider.

You can take a look at the [PackageManagement cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-6)

You would have to manage the **providers and sources** depending upon the available packages.

[Create your own Local Package Feed](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx)

If you want to create your own local repository: [Creating Local NuGet Repository](https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/)

To call a Powershell script after Install-Package command, create a file called as install.ps1 and add the below code:

```
Install-Package -Name 7Zip4Powershell
<Your stuff, for e.g;> 
Get-ChildItem
Get-Hotfix
```

To run the script: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install.ps1`

If you have a code apart from Install-Package in a different ps1 file, then you can call the script:

```
Install-Package -Name 7zip4powershell
.\MyCode.ps1
```

Check out this link: [Running PowerShell scripts during NuGet package installation and removal](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html)

[Package Management in Windows Powershell](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/managing-packages-using-windows-powershell/)

**Lastly,** if you really want to see whats the **code** inside `Install-Package`, check out: [Disassemble Powershell cmdlet](https://technet.blogs.ms/disassemble-powershell-cmdlets/)
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Rajiv Iyer, The article links to the topic I mentioned above, that everything I find is related to Visual Studio. But I do not have a Nuget Package with any Visual Studio Libraries - I have a Nuget Package with, let's say, 7zip I want do install in Windows.

Comment: You can create a wrapper (ps1) file which contains the commands to install 7zip and do the other required stuff

Comment: Yes, but how is that script executed using PowerShell only? i.e. the command Install-Package

Comment: Do you just want to execute the Install-Package Command that will do everything? Can you also elaborate your query? I have updated my post.

Comment: I have a package I created on my own in my own Repository. I can use Install-Package and Remove-Package commands. So technically that works so far. As far as I see, these commands simply unpack files from the nuget-Package and does not execute anything. Because I want to run everything from one command ("Install-Package") without a second command, I asked this questions. Your Link "Running PowerShell scripts during NuGet package installation and removal" is again just for Visual Studio that executes this install.ps1-file after the nuget package was extracted.Maybe Chocolatey is my only option?

Comment: In this case you would have to take a look at the cmdlet definition and add your steps in that, which I think is the best way to start with.